# Iterating list of floats in a condition throws an error

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate a list of floats however the condition throws me a **TypeError**.

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

The error is thrown at the line `for i in numList[1:]:`

How do I fix it? what cause it?

```
def checkSeries(numList):
    flagSeries=-1
    for i in numList[1:]:
        if i < numList[i-1]:
            if flagSeries==1:
                return -1
            flagSeries=0
        else:
            if flagSeries==0:
                return -1
            flagSeries=1
            
        return flagSeries
```

Comment: yoiu're mixing up indices with values. `i` is a value not an indice. You need `enumerate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying in line `for i in numList[1:]:` is getting the item but not index. Seeing your code, I assume you want to iterate using indexes.

Try,

```
def checkSeries(numList):
    flagSeries = -1
    for i in range(1, len(numList)):
        if numList[i] < numList[i - 1]:
            if flagSeries == 1:
                return -1
            flagSeries = 0
        else:
            if flagSeries == 0:
                return -1
            flagSeries = 1

        return flagSeries
```

Comment: oh god how did i missed it, so embarrassing, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `numList[i]` because `i` is a float. Think about it - if we had the list:

```
numList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and tried to do `numList[0]`, it would return `1`. But, what would happen for `numList[0.1]`? Or any other float value?

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, but your culprit is the fourth line - `numList[i - 1]`. Maybe use `for i in range(len(1, numList))` instead of setting `i` to each value in `numList`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `i` both as an index to access `numList` and as an element of your list. Instead, try :

```
def checkSeries(numList):
    flagSeries=-1
    for i in range(1, len(numList)):
        if numList[i] < numList[i-1]:
            if flagSeries==1:
                return -1
            flagSeries=0
        else:
            if flagSeries==0:
                return -1
            flagSeries=1
            
        return flagSeries
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the index while iterating over the list, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate):

```
def checkSeries(numList):
    flagSeries=-1
    for index, value in enumerate(numList[1:], start=1):
        if value < numList[index-1]:
            if flagSeries==1:
                return -1
            flagSeries=0
        else:
            if flagSeries==0:
                return -1
            flagSeries=1        
    return flagSeries
```